# Unable to boot into Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu alongside with my Windows 8. I have 3 partitions.
After installing Ubuntu I am unable to boot into Windows 8.

The error screen that I get says:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD  

  Status: 0xc000000c  

  Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

I tried running Boot-Repair, but it still hasn't worked. <s>Here's the [boot repair link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6711446)</s>. Also here's a screenshot from GParted.

[image]

Comment: You seem to have an efi partition and gpt partitioning. But Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI. And Windows looks like it is in BIOS mode? Did you do a hybrid gpt/MBR partition scheme? Sometimes used with Macs but not recommended normally.  http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html

Comment: A few months ago, I did try a hackintosh installation with GPT partitioning and dual boot with the Windows 8. But after a while, I decided to remove the hackintosh installation by formatting the drive. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows partition you are using is for gaming then I understand you want to fix the error but if you are not using it for gaming I suggest you install Virtualbox and that you install Windows inside Ubuntu, it works great.

To solve the problem try the following, repeat it several times:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2843-automatic-repair-run-windows-8-a.html

If you can't get the problem solved that way just refresh:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2293-refresh-windows-8-a.html

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: Thanks for replying but I still need to use Windows, not for gaming but I also use it for Visual Effects related stuff and also run some Internet marketing software on Windows.

I tried using the methods above but I cannot even get to the Windows recovery screen when I boot from my DVD. 
"There was a problem with a device connected to your PC"
"An unexpected I/O error has occured."
"Error Code 0xc00000e9"